# Webpack reference require module in Html

Tags: javascript, razor, requirejs, webpack

I'm trying to convert a requirejs project to use webpack. In the Index page, before the webpacked bundle.js script is called, a requirejs module is defined inline that uses some Razor directives to set some js variables from the c# controller. This requirejs module is then referenced a few places in other js files.

When I try webpacking my js files, obviously webpack can't find this module, and I can't separate it into its own js file because it contains Razor statements.

I can't think of a way around this, but perhaps there is? Help, please...

Comment: Can you post some code to help explain?

Comment: And why do you need to require the module?  Couldnt you put the variables on the global scope?

Comment: Yea, you are right. I was totally over thinking it. That works fine.